# VueJS Firebase cloud messaging

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

I tried use FCM to show desktop notifications in my vue app

I installed firebase and initializeApp with my config

So i install sw-precache-webpack-plugin and i have service-worker.js in my dist folder

i have same errors
[image]

sw-precache config

```
new SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin({
      cacheId: 'service-app',
      filename: 'service-worker.js',
      staticFileGlobs: ['dist/**/*.{js,html,css}'],
      minify: false,
      stripPrefix: 'dist/'
  })
```

in index.html`<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.serviceWorkerLoader %>`

can eat without sw-precache-webpack-plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I had to make a hardcore

create firebase-messaging-sw.js  and move to dist folder in production server